# Method is not returning the update from API response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Reiterating my question. This is what i am trying to do. But the issue is return paramarray is not listing the update which i did in if condition. I will be rendering this in my react cards. Can someone please suggest if i am missing something here. I am able to get the output of obj.FileName which means its working fine inside the for loop but when i returning its not having that update which i did in if condition.

Below is the code

```
method(paramarray){
var test;    
for(var i = 0; i < paramarray.length; i++) {
var obj = paramarray[i];
if(obj.Id == 10){
 fetch(geturl,{headers})
.then(function (response) {
return response.json();
})
  .then(function (data) {
  test  = data.data;
  obj.FileName = test[0].Name;
})
}
else{
// Do nothing
 }
 }
 return  paramarray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both of your components are in the same project, you can pass variables (recommended state variables):

- As a prop: <CardComponent title={myname_10}
- Or through a store (depends which one you use: ContextAPI, Redux, Mobx, ...)

For some unknown reason you try to pass it through the URL, which is not best practice, but if there is a special reason for it, then ok.

If you want to do it with API calls, then you have to fetch the response and save the array in your state variable (of Card Component) or your store.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, just edited my code  to be accurate of what i am trying to do.

Comment: Not working even after setting the state in the method,

Comment: Problem is i am getting proper values inside for loop but not able to get that update outside of for loop

Comment: Do you update the state value? With setState for hooks.